# Android FCM Notification Not Popping Up

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my Android app, the Push Notification Firebase Cloud Messaging is only received on the device when the user is not in the app at the time of sending - The message is received, but not displayed. I made a console.writeline to log if the message was received, and it was, but no sound was made and the notification didn't pop up.

Some background:

- I am testing on an emulator
- I am using the `FirebasePushNotification Plugin` (as it is a Xamarin.Forms project and I want to be able to do cross-platform setup
- I have downloaded GoogleServicesJSON, set build action, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are sending the [Data messages](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/docs/FirebaseNotifications.md#firebase-push-notifications),When using this type of message you are the one providing the UI and handling when push notification is received on an Android device.

So you should define and create your notification yourself in the receive callback.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am sending from the Firebase Console - would this make it a Data Message?

Comment: Just sending the basic "Title" "Message"

Comment: Try to put your app in the background and try sending the push notification again.